# How to make React Bootstrap Carousel Fade Effect smooth

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the react-bootstrap library Carousel with Fade={true}, but the effect is not smooth. It flashes instantly on image change instead of fading. how can I make it smooth that?

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me. So use the !important to overwrite the default.

In the CSS file:

```
.carousel-item {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out !important;
}
li{
transition: opacity 1s ease !important;
}
```